# keyboard input is not working in emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-emulator

I have latest Android studio version 3.1.3 and I have all updated tools and versions in SDK.

I have created Different AVDs with keyboard support. And then I noticed that none of them is taking keyboard input. I have double check that if the keyboard support is enabled in advance settings of AVD.

I have checked and unchecked that keyboard support but got no luck. I have created different emulators with earlier versions from Oreo to jellybeans but none of them was taking keyboard input

Then I thought that it might be my machine issue because keyboard input was working before as expected, so I thought to change the machine.

I changed not only machine but whole environment, I have created emulator on Mini mac (ios_) but still I found that Keyboard is not working.

So did anyone noticed this issue? Is this a serious issue in updated versions of Android studio? (I think android studio 2.2 was the one which was taking input in the emulator from my hardware PC keyboard) ???

> Please help me, I have searched it on SO but none of them work and
>   those questions are even too old. I have also changed the settings
>   file of the emulators but it is not working. It's my 4th day and still
>   got no luck. Any idea about this bug?

Comment: Please can you share the Screenshot of your emulator with menu option from side?

Comment: what menu options ?

Comment: I am talking about this one. http://prntscr.com/k5ldcl

Comment: its the same , as you posted in link \

Comment: Post your relevant XML and Java code please. Also if possible, post a small video link so that we can see the exact behavior.

Comment: of which activity ?

Comment: @Androidteem Create an emulator with latest version of android. I have my emulator with API 27 and is working perfectly. Also add screenshot of your Emulator Advance Settings.

Comment: I have created with advance version too , but its nt working thoguh